# Как оптимизировать вычисление корреляции для большой матрицы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Есть два датафрейма `df1` и `df2`. Мне нужно найти максимальный коэффициент корреляции каждой строки из `df1` со всем датафреймом `df2`.

**Вот мой алгоритм:**
Я итеративно беру строку из `df1` и вычисляю коэффициент корреляций с каждой строкой из второго датафрейма `df2`. Ответы записываю в список. Затем просто беру максимальное значение из списка и заношу его в новый столбец в датафрейм `df1`.

Моя проблема - очень медленная работа скрипта. Я перенес вычисления из pandas в numpy, но выиграл примерно 20% времени, но все равно это очень долго.

Ниже привожу свой код. У меня он выполняется 26 минут. Датафрейм тестовый и урезанный примерно в 10 раз.

Что я делаю неправильно? Поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

fn = 'https://st.storeland.ru/6/2433/813/big_df1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=0, delimiter=',')
df = df.iloc[1:, :].reset_index(drop=True).T.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df / np.random.randint(1, 3) # немного изменяю первый датафрейм
df2 = pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True) # увеличиваю второй датафрейм


print('Долгая функция NumPy')

nf = np.array(df2) # перобразую датафрейм в  numpy-массив. Он быстрее работает.

def noise(seria):
  mas = []
  timer = timeit.default_timer()
  
  for i in nf:
    mas.append(float('{:.4f}'.format(np.corrcoef(seria, i)[1,0])))
  return max(mas)
  
  
timer = timeit.default_timer()
df1['max_noise'] = df1.apply(noise, axis=1)
print('Затрачено: ', round(timeit.default_timer() - timer, 8), 'сек.\n')
df1.iloc[-5:, -6:]
```

И в тоже время если выполнить просто корреляцию большой матрицы, то она намного быстрее работает. У меня большие подозрения, что функция `apply` очень тормознутая.

Вот та же матрица с простой корреляцией работает наверное в сотни раз быстрее:

```html
fn = 'https://st.storeland.ru/6/2433/813/big_df1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=0, delimiter=',')
df = df.iloc[1:, :].reset_index(drop=True).T.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df / np.random.randint(1, 3) # немного изменяю первый датафрейм
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True) # увеличиваю второй датафрейм
  
timer = timeit.default_timer()
dfd = df2.T.corr()
print('Затрачено: ', round(timeit.default_timer() - timer, 8), 'сек.\n')
dfd.iloc[-5:, -6:]
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что приходит в голову. Поскольку у вас заранее известно количество строк в каждом датафрейме,  mas объявлять статически и одноразово. Просто известно, что append -  весьма медленная операция, особенно для больших списков.

При более внимательном рассмотрении: список mas - вообще не нужен как таковой. Достаточно искать максимум в динамически генерируемом потоке.  Примерно так:

> ```
> Max_in_df2=-2
> for i in nf:
>     Cur_Corr=np.corrcoef(seria, i)
>     if Cur_Corr> Max_in_df2:
>         Max_in_df2=Cur_Corr
> return Max_in_df2
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!
Время выполнения сократилось но лишь на пару процентов. Все равно это долго.